# accessing the nginx page hosted on a port forwarded machine - Red Hat Linux

Tags: node.js, nginx, redhat, portforwarding

i have a domain, which points to different IP addresses(Red Hat instances) when different port numbers are given along with the domain name.

like "mydomainname:51011 ---> 10.2.34.56",
"mydomainname:51012 ---> 10.2.34.57",
"mydomainname:51013 ---> 10.2.34.58".

I can currently SSH into the machines using putty and providing different port numbers with the domain name. and no GUI access as of now.

**My Question -**

I have nginx setup on machine "10.2.34.56". How do i view its page on my browser.
Also, please suggest how i can access a node server running, on say port 50001 on that machine.
Thanks,

**EDITS:**

nginx is up and running - i am trying to access ""mydomainname:51011"" in my browser, but it does not seem to work.

i can see the text "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3" in the browser, when i put the above URL

Comment: > i have a domain, which points to different IP addresses(Red Hat instances) when different port numbers are given along with the domain name.

It's not possible. Probably you mean something different, like you have proxy or similar. Clarify, please

Comment: I can SSH into different server instances based on the port number, like i have shown in the second paragraph. with an example.